# Canon 450D photos come out half

Tags: canon

My Canon EOS 450D after does not show a full picture, but all photos taken are black on the sides. [image]

I am also getting an 'Error 99' message on Canon 450D.

Comment: After what? Also, do these show up only on the LCD screen or are they photos themselves like this?

Comment: Did you ensure that nothing is blocking the lens?

Comment: Is the mirror flipping properly? If none of those are the problem, it could be a fault in the sensor.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a faulty shutter is blocking parts of the sensor.

It could also be something else blocking light from reaching the sensor. Based on the definition of the edges of the dark parts it would have to be something fairly close to the image sensor, though.

An 'Error 99' in the Canon system is a fairly general error and could indicate a problem in any one of several areas. Before giving up and sending the camera in for servicing (or abandoning the camera because it is not worth what fixing it would cost), try these steps. They're what Canon will tell you to do if you contact them before allowing you to send them a Canon camera that is under warranty if it is throwing 'Error 99' codes when shooting.

1. Carefully clean the 8 gold color lens contact pins on the camera body 
   lens mount with a pencil eraser. Do this while holding the camera so that 
   any eraser dust will not fall into the camera.
2. Take out both batteries. Yes, there are two. The main battery and the 
   smaller Date/Time battery. Also remove the CF memory card.
3. With the batteries removed, turn the camera switch on for 3-5 minutes. 
   This clears the memory.
4. Turn the camera off and put the batteries and CF card back in.
5. Re-attach the lens and turn it back on.

If you have more than one lens and/or battery and/or CF card, use different ones when you turn the camera back on. If only one lens causes the 'Error 99', then the lens is faulty. Carefully clean the contacts on the lens. If that doesn't work then the lens is faulty. If only one battery or one CF card causes the 'Error 99', then either the battery or CF card is faulty. Replace with a different battery or CF card.

But in your case, the example image strongly suggest the issue in your case is with the shutter.

Answer (score -2):

This is a problem that plagues beginners. Under dim lighting conditions and when we want to fill in shadows, we resort to using a flash. Now the flash mimics a lightning blitz. In other words, the flash fires, its light lingers for about 1/1000 of a second, and then it quenches. The camera’s shutter is supposed to open completely. This action allows the entire area of the image sensor to be uncovered in synchronization with the blitz. Now cameras of this type use a special type of a shutter called a “focal plane” shutter. This mechanism is a curtain that hovers just over the image sensor. When you press the go button, the curtain moves, and in doing so, uncovers the image senor so it can record your picture.

Sounds simple but there is a hitch. The uncovering and the shutter speed timing is accomplished by a fast moving slit in the curtain. This slit uncovers the imaging chip and then re-covers it as it moves. The shutter speed is actually the time it takes to move the distance of the slit width. When you change shutter speeds you are adjusting the dimensions of the slit width.

When using a flash, we want the slit width to be large enough to uncover the entire area of the imaging chip. If the shutter speed is set to high, the slit width will be too small to uncover the entire chip. If you check your camera manual, you will find that when using flash, you need to keep the shutter speed at 1/200 of a second or slower. Such a setting assures that the entire imaging chip is uncovered in sync with the blitz. If you set the shutter too fast, the blitz captures the slit in focal plane shutter while it is moving. The result is that one half of the image area is lopped off.

One caveat: You can use a faster shutter if your flash supports “high speed sync”. This is a specialized flash unit that has an elongated blitz duration. This type of unit keeps the flash on all the while a narrow slit (setting for high shutter speed) is traveling across the sensor chip.

It won’t hurt to read the camera manual.

Comment: Having the shutter speed faster than the flash sync speed results in horizontal darkness, but this can't explain the vertical darkness as well.

Comment: @ Phillip - You are right, I did not study the posted image close enough. Likely this is a case of the shutter malfunctioning. It still might be sync is the shutter opens and closes in a rectangular pattern. That's a possibility!

Comment: This is a daylight exposure. Regardless of the shape, the described problem wouldn't occur here. Also, the camera won't allow an exposure time below sync speed.